# I can't mount a windows 10 shared drive on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, cifs

I have a shared directory under windows set to full access for everyone.  When I use mount.cifs it just hangs there, and when I use smbclient I get the following error?  I can connects to share fine using my android phone.  It is especially wierd that it says "login successful" but then access denied.  Is that a clue?

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.74/backups /mnt/backups/ -o guest,soft --verbose

smbclient //MY-WINDOWS/backups -N -U Everyone 
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[MY-WINDOWS] OS=[Windows 10 Pro 15063] Server=[Windows 10 Pro 6.3]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Comment: Anonyous login to sharing host can be successful, then you can be denied access for the specific resource. Pretty normal.

Comment: Do not use the Guest-Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using a real user/password instead of guest/Everyone account.